# ios autolayout not aligning properly

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I have problem with autolayout I do not understand.

I have a UITableView and it contains a simple UITableViewCell. Within this UITableViewCell I got a UIView that serves as a background with alpah 0.61.

This is the structure in my storyboard:

[image]

And this is my design in the storyboard:

[image]

As you can probably see, I set the layout constraints that the UIView object exaclty as wide as the cell itself and also snaps to the bottom. So no margin should be remain.

Now, this is the final result:

[image]

So, what is going on and where does this margin come from?

Note: I'm using XCode 6.4.

Comment: please show a bigger screenshot of the interface builder.

Comment: here is the solution:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31399330/how-to-remove-margin-from-a-viewcontroller/31399373#31399373

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add new constraints in storyboard just disable:

Constraints to margins

(as default, when you add a class extending UIView, using storyboard, margin are enabled)

Comment: Yes that was it. Strange that I did not encouter this problem earlier. Thanks